# Space between bar chart with day/week/month in x axis in R

Tags: r, date, bar-chart

When the number of bars is large (when days/weeks are on x axis), the spaces between the bars are not visible.
[image: Refer this bar plot]

But when the number of bars are small (when months are on x axis), the spaces between the bars are vsiible.
[image: Refer tthis bar plot]

What i want is irrespective of number of bars, the spaces between the bars should be visible. Any idea to code in R please?

Comment: are you using ggplot?

Comment: Yes, I am using ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `colour = "white"` for the border around the bars:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = rep(1:100, 5)) 

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(colour = "white")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: But I am plotting bar chart, not histogram. Could you please tell how to plot bar chart like that?

Comment: `geom_col()` if you have x and y. `geom_bar()` if you are counting x. `colour = "white"` will still work with the border where needed.  Generally it's better if you can provide a reproducible example like mine that includes a sample of your data, then it's easier for us to replicate and improve on what you've done or tried.

Comment: I got what I expected from using color = 'white'. Thank you so much :)